# How to populate subdocument with other fields in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
 name: { type: String, require: true },
 comments: [{
  id: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment'},
  vote: Number,
 }],
 creator: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
```

I can populate `creator`, but cannot populate `comment`

```
Posts
.findOne({ id: id })
.populate('creator')
.populate('comments')
.exec(function (err, post) {
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this one, with `comments.id` as below

```
Posts
    .findOne({ id: id })
    .populate('creator')
    .populate('comments.id')
    .exec(function (err, post) {
    });
```